# How to ssh port forward and access browser

Tags: ssh, portforwarding

There are complicated situation.
Participants: Laptop, development server, server2, server1.

1. From my laptop via ssh I need access development server (ssh only).
2. From development server I need access server2 (ssh only).
3. From servers2 browser (lynx) I need access server1 (uses https).

Is it possible to forward ssh ports and access server1 using my laptop browser?
Please, advice me :)

Comment: So, in the end, you need to tunnel a HTTPS connection through SSH port forwarding? - Then your browser may cause issues with the HTTPS certificate, because it does not know about the port forwarding and may complain about non-matching hostnames.

Comment: [Remote Port Forwading](http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html) may be for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you forward your ssh port, you cannot connect to the original server anymore. However, you can assign your ssh server different ports. These can be forwarded.